# How to add foreign key migrations in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

```
$this->dbforge->add_field(['CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)']);
```

The error coming from this code

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

Can anyone identify how this code produces the error?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$this->dbforge->add_column('table',[
    'CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES table(id)',
]);
```

Or

```
$this->dbforge->add_field('CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES table(id)');
```